# How to go about creating 54 individual post cards that create a map when all put together?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, design-principles, maps

I need to create 54 individual post cards/ brochure cards that all have different graphic designs on them. When they are all laid out they need to create a map of the world. For instance, one of the 54 cards will have just a small section of the world (maybe a country) and then when placed with the others it creates an image.

I have photoshop and illustrator but have never used them before. Willing to learn. Just need to know if this is doable.

Comment: Yes it is possible. *How* to do this may be a bit too broad for a question here.

Comment: And some cards will be pretty boring... The midle of the pacific ocean... Sometimes a idea that sounds good just need a lot of effort to put it in practice. If you have no practice on thoose programs, try doing you have already done, like manual ilustration.

Comment: @Rafael: boring? Maybe not... the Map application that came with old black-and-white Macintoshes had a funny easter egg: you could search for locations, and "middle of nowhere" pointed out the center of the Atlantic.

Comment: It was kind of a joke. Yes, probably you can put some native culture, or some sea snakes :o)

Answer (score 3):

Dimensions for desired specs of one card. Multiply that by 54. Create a new document with these dimensions. Create a map of the world at the size of this document. Select piece by piece saving each as its own file. Print. Profit.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on individual card dimensions, you could create one Illustrator document with 54 artboards, each butted up against the other. Then find/create your 'whole-world' vector artwork, and resize it so it spans the full width/height of your artboard array. Then save the Illustrator file as PDF, with each artboard as a separate page.